Elastic search bulk Api- creating new index vs upserting where ~90% docs will update
This is very use case specific problem statement. I am dividing a document in my index (test index)
for example in 2 section
{
 // section 1 - details less likely to change
 uid: 123,
 name: 'John',
 email: 'email@email.com'

 // section 2 - details may change on daily basis
 counter1: 2,
 counter2: 1,
 counter3: 0,
 .
 .
 .
}

Data in the test index pushed everyday through bulk APIs, where 90 percent of the docs getting updated, and there is very few new docs that are inserted.
In this scenario can I create new index and delete the old one. What will be performance implications here.
Currently i am always doing upserts using id's creating in code. Right now the scale of data is very small and it is performing very well, Also i have tried second approach with creating new index and deleting old one while using alias. Performance was same, as scale is small.
But keeping in mind each doc in immutable in ES, performing updates on 90% of docs in index can be bad decision. And if go with creating new index, possibly that also includes some disadvantages. Looking for any other appropriate approach i can follow or any correction and disadvantages in current approach.
